# How to encapsulate a Map into a custom object

Tags: java, oop, dictionary, enums

My coworker tells me that it's lazy to use Maps, and that oftentimes the programmer's purpose would be better served by an actual object. But I don't know the best way to do so. This is further complicated (to me) by the fact that the key is an Enum type.

Say I have a `Hashmap<MyEnum, MyObj>` which is expected to have four hashmap keys (one for each value in `MyEnum`). The `MyObj` hashmap value is the latest of several MyObjs in a database which have the given enum value.

My best guess involves an object with four fields, or maybe two arrays containing the keys and values in order.

Not sure if this is clear or not (It's 5PM on Thursday = I'm brain-dead), so please ask for clarification if necessary.

Comment: Your coworker is wrong.  There's nothing "lazy" about using a Map when a Map is the appropriate data structure.  If your key is an enum type, there's an optimized `EnumMap` you can use.

Comment: I totally agree with @JimGarrison. There's nothing wrong on using Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's nothing wrong with using Maps for their intended purpose, Maps are sometimes misused as substitutes for strongly-typed objects.

```
String firstname = (String)myMap.get("first_name");
```

... as opposed to:

```
String firstName = person.getFirstName();
```

Since Java implements enums as classes, you might want to consider putting the value you're looking for onto your enum class directly:

```
MyEnum val = getVal();
MyObj obj = val.getMostRecentMyObj();
```

But I'd pay attention to separation of concerns to determine whether this really makes sense. It could well be that a Map is the appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you know in advance **exactly** what keys a map will have and you have to modify code to work with different keys, that's probably the point where map is being misused. With enums though it's arguable, since enums are immutable. But even then you can use composition and create a class that contains an enum value and the associated object.

Comment: An important and interesting difference between these approaches is that if you make the associated object a field of the enum, you force the developer to provide one with each and every value of the enum. Whereas if you use maps, there's nothing guaranteeing that.

Comment: @biziclop: Regarding your first comment, I think it depends somewhat on the intended usage. If people are writing code that says `myMap.get(MyEnum.A)`, then they're definitely misusing Maps--there should be specific fields or getter methods or something for each of the enum's values. However, if the value is determined dynamically based on data at runtime, there's nothing wrong with having a Map as the underlying data structure. (Obviously you'd want to hide it behind some sort of interface method so the implementation can change as necessary.)

Comment: @biziclop: To your second comment, that is an important point, but you're not necessarily forcing the developer to provide these. The enum class can define, for example, how to *get* the appropriate value on the fly. It could even be using a static `Map` as a backing object to store this information.

Comment: Exactly, hence the second clause of the rule. If however the map is both filled and queried statically, alarm bells should go off.